# Edge Detection with qTip2

Tags: jquery, iframe, tooltip, qtip, qtip2

I'm using [qTip2](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/). I thought it included screen detection - however, I am using the tooltip within an iframe, and it isn't working:

[image: screenshot showing tooltip hidden under edge of iframe]

I tried:

```
position: {
    adjust: {screen: true},
    my: 'bottom center',  // Position my top left...
    at: 'top center' // at the bottom right of...
},
```

It didn't work

Comment: have you tried adjusting the qTip's width using the 'style' property? why not make the width smaller than the secure login box? also, aTip isn't exactly centered on the input. do you have the input width specified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The qTip2 plugin has a `viewport` option:

```
position: {
    my: 'bottom center',  // Position my top left...
    at: 'top center', // at the bottom right of...
    adjust: {
        screen: true
    },
    viewport: $(window)
},
```

It fixes this scenario.